# Django and bootstrap, why my widget does not work?

Tags: html, django, bootstrap-4, django-forms, django-templates

I have the following html's boostrap code:

```
 <div class="input-group date col-2" id="datetimepicker1" data-target-input="nearest">
    {{form.data_contabile|as_crispy_field}}
 <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker1" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
 <div class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-clock"></i></div>
 </div>
 </div>

    <script>
      $(function () {
        $("#datetimepicker1").datetimepicker({
          format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
        });
      });
    </script>
```

And in my form the following code:

```
class MaterialeForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Materiale
    fields = "__all__"
    exclude = ['iva_amount']
    widgets = {'data_contabile': forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={ 'type':'text', 
                                                             'class':'form-control datetimepicker-input', 
                                                             'data-target': '#datetimepicker1'})}
```

and finally my models:

```
class Materiale(models.Model):
    data_contabile=models.DateField('Data di acquisto', default="GG/MM/YYYY")
```

But the layout are the following:

[image]

Where is the error?

Answer (score 2):

Acc to the datetimepicker [documentation](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) here you should call datetimepicker function on the id of element and not data-target of your element. Either you change your Model Form attributes like this:

```
class Meta:
model = Materiale
fields = "__all__"
exclude = ['iva_amount']
widgets = {'data_contabile': forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={ 'type':'text', 
                                                         'class':'form-control datetimepicker-input', 
                                                         'id': 'datetimepicker1'})}
```

This should work like this

or

You can change your can change your selector to call datetimepicker jquery function on element with data-target attribute like this:

```
$('[data-target=#datetimepicker1]').datetimepicker({
      format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    });
```

Either way this should work.